# How to update dist folder so Heroku serves up new code?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm

I'm new to node and deploying. I understand that every change I make on master branch I need to commit and push. My Heroku app doesn't update when doing so and I've worked out its because its serving the files from my /dist folder in the repo.

So i was wondering, whenever I change my code do I have to delete my dist folder and run "npm run build" again so my dist folder is up to date or?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your build process involves (you can post your package.json if you want) but you might not need to delete your dist folder, otherwise, yes. You build your code and then deploy it.

One way to automate this would be to set up a Continuous Delivery process. This would be a build server like Jenkins or a service like Semaphore CI that is triggered on a push, builds your code for you, and deploys it.

**Edit:** If you're using a vue-cli template like their `webpack` template you don't need to delete the dist directory, the build script handles that for you. @m-ketan's suggestion of using Heroku's build hooks is a good one but I think you might want to use `postinstall` and have it call `npm run build`. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/844

Comment: There isnt much to my package.json file but

{
  "name": "game-of-trivia",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Jonathan Puc",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },

It was basically a boilerplate from vue-cli. Then using express. I thought simply comitting and pushing changes would update my heroku app but it doesnt. I have to delete my dist folder, make it again and then push if I want to update my app.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually replacing the `dist` folder on every heroku deploy. You need to remove the existing `dist` folder on your heroku server. So for handling this you can use the `heroku preinstall` script hook. Your `package.json` file should look like this:

```
scripts: {
  preinstall: "rm -rf /dist"
}
```

You can now run your script for deploying on heroku and it'll first remove the `dist` folder and then deploy a fresh build.